# On the pdf of a modified distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

We have the intersection of two equal circles in the figure on the left. A number of random points are uniformly distributed between UQWD and the pdf is given as $f(r)= \frac{l(r)}{A}$. On the right of this diagram a number of random points are also uniformly distributed (not in the intersection of two circles as the first but) within a circle of radius $R$. The pdf is given as $\frac{2r}{R^2}$. Now we are given a modified distribution in case 2 for the distributed points within the circle and we would like to determine the pdf in the context of the area between two intersecting circles. This is not a homework but is a practical problem.

As hinted by @Lee David Chung Lin in the comments, the modified distribution can be described as a truncated Rayleigh distribution.

Comment: There's an error in your modified density. Either it should be $\displaystyle \frac{ \lambda \pi r e^{-\lambda \pi r^2 / 2} }{1 - \lambda \pi r e^{-\lambda \pi R^2 / 2} }$, or it should be $\displaystyle \frac{ \lambda \pi r e^{-\lambda \pi r^2 } }{2 \left( 1 - \lambda \pi r e^{-\lambda \pi R^2}\right) }$. Please check the normalization yourself. Either way, the exponents should have the same factor.

Comment: BTW, this is the truncated [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution), which is Normally distributed in both the two independent directions in Cartesian coordinates. This is a prominent and common model, rather than some arbitrary choice. You can add this in the post to have more context (instead of just calling it a "modified" distribution) to reduce the chance of being downvoted. (Currently I see that you have 2 upvotes and 1 downvote)

Comment: Thanks for the above comments, I have corrected this in the question. Your comment was beneficial and timely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall assume your [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) (which is a radial density with rotational symmetry) is meant to have the following form where the variance (for the underlying Gaussian) is $\sigma^2 = \frac1{\lambda \pi}$:
$$f_r(r) = K_1 \cdot \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }  \, , \qquad \text{where} ~~K_1 \equiv \Bigl(1 - \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi R^2}2 } \Bigr)^{-1}$$

Accordingly, the conditional radial density in $\Omega \equiv \text{UQWD region}$ takes the form

$$f_{r|\Omega} = \frac{ L(r) }K \, , \qquad \text{where}~~L(r) = 2\cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{r}{2R}\bigr) \cdot K_1 \cdot \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }$$

and $K$ is the total probability mass of $\Omega$.

Indeed, the functional form of the density $L(r)$ can be obtained by simply multiplying $2\cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{r}{2R}\bigr)$ to whatever the radial density that is given (the factor of 2 is just due to reflective symmetry). So if you were wondering whether one can take this "shortcut" by translating what is seen in the uniform case, then the answer is yes.

The derivation of this fact is easy and requires only some elementary analytic geometry and the basics of joint density. Let me know if you need that.

However, the total mass of $\Omega$ requires actually calculating the integral

$$K = 2 \cdot \left( \frac16 + K_1 \int_{r = 0}^R \int_{\theta = \cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{-r}{2R}\bigr)}^{\frac{2\pi}3} \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }  \,d\theta\, dr \right) $$

Note that there's a negative sign in the arccosine, as the angle is in the 3rd quadrant ($\frac{\pi}2 < \theta < \pi$).

\begin{align}
K &= \frac13 + 2 K_1\int_{r = 0}^R \left( \frac{2\pi}3 - \cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{-r}{2R}\bigr) \right) \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }  \,dr \\
&= \frac13 + 2 K_1\int_{r = 0}^R \left( \cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{r}{2R}\bigr) - \frac{\pi}3 \right) \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }
\end{align}
which doesn't have a closed form. Nonetheless, numerical evaluation to high precision of such a simple functional form is easy. For example, for $\lambda = 1$ and $R = 1$, we have $K \approx  0.0297988491$.

Since you said this comes from a practical problem and not a homework, it's not a surprise that numerical methods have to be employed.

Comment: "Let me know if you need that." - Yes! Lee David Chung Lin, I will appreciate that! Then please, may I ask about how you came about $k= 2(\frac{1}{6} + ..d\theta dr)$

Comment: @Abdulhameed Okay the math is easy but it would take some time to make the diagram and type up the post. Don't expect it to be finished within today. As for the $\frac16 + \cdots$ it is just that the circular sector (pizza shaped) with angle $\pi/3$ (from $2\pi/3$ to $\pi$) always takes one sixth of the mass for any rotationally distribution. Note the integral lower limit is arccosine and upper limit is $2\pi/3$

Comment: In case there is any reference where it is solved, that would also be nice, otherwise, you can make a sketch and attach as a picture, I would take the time to draw and write it. Thanks

Comment: Then permit me to ask about how $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ was derived as the upper limit for $d\theta$

Comment: In the conventional polar coordinate, point $D$ in your diagram is the center, and the angle starts at the "right hand side" growing counter-clockwise. That is, point $U$ is at $\theta = 2\pi/3$ and point $Q$ is at $\theta = \pi$. The circular sector (pizza) that has $\frac16$ of the mass has the boundary consisting of the two straightedges ($\overline{DU}$ and $\overline{DQ}$) and the circular arc $\overset{\frown}{UQ}$

Comment: The integral is over the region on the upper-right of that pizza, which boundary is a straightedge $\overline{DU}$ and the circular arc (from the left circle) $\overset{\frown}{DU}$, or $\widetilde{DAU}$ if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I quite like this answer and will take time to study it further.

Comment: Thank you for those beautiful answers. Now I understand the rationale behind having $\frac{1}{6}$, but please I was wondering why you added it to $$K_1 \int_{r = 0}^R \int_{\theta = \cos^{-1}\bigl(\frac{-r}{2R}\bigr)}^{\frac{2\pi}3} \lambda \pi r e^{- \dfrac{\lambda \pi r^2}2 }  \,d\theta\, dr$$.  By the way, I would appreciate to know what software you used to draw those beautiful  illustrations. Thanks

Comment: (1) In the last figure of the other post, the $\frac16$ is the gray circular sector, and the integral is the purple region. $\text{gray}+\text{purple}$ is the upper half of your desired UQWD.  (2) The diagrams here are made with GeoGebra, it's free. Another popular one is Desmos. Different apps have their own strengths. Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant and beautiful answer

Answer (score 2):

As per requested in the first comment of the earlier post,let me do this in a separate post cuz it's too long as an appendix.

### About the "shortcut" of $~2\cos^{-1}\bigl( \frac{r}{2R}\bigr) \cdot f_r(r)$

The mass over a general region $\Omega$ for a 2-dim distribution expressed in polar form is

$$\iint_{\Omega} f_{r\Theta}(r, \theta)\, dr d\theta $$

where $f_{r\Theta}$ is the joint density that can be complicated where variables $r$ and $\theta$ are tangled. Note that the integral is just $drd\theta$ and NOT the usual $rdrd\theta = dxdy$ under the Cartesian-polar transformation. The convention is that we consider the Jacobian (the extra term $r$) is absorbed into the density.

When the radial direction and the angular component are independent, we have the [basic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Independence)
$$f_{r\Theta}(r, \theta) = f_r(r) \cdot f_{\Theta}(\theta)$$
That is, the variables $r$ and $\theta$ are separable.

If further we have rotationally symmetric distribution, which means the angle itself is uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi)$, then

$$f_{\Theta}(\theta) = \frac1{2\pi}$$

Note that both uniform (over a disk) and Rayleigh (either over the whole plane or truncated to just a disk) are both rotationally symmetric by definition.

Accordingly, the mass when the region $\Omega = UQWD$ as given is the integral

$$2\int_{r = 0}^R \left[ \int_{\theta = T(r) }^{\pi} f_r(r) \cdot \frac1{2\pi} \, d\theta \right] dr  = 2\int_{r = 0}^R \frac{ \pi - T(r) }{ 2\pi }  f_r(r) dr$$
where $T(r)$ traces out the curve $\widetilde UAD$ (the circluar arc of the left circle) is the angle as a function of the radial distance.

The whole thing is mirror symmetric with respect to the horizontal axis (the extended line $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{QU}$) so there's a factor of 2 in front and the upper limit of angle is $\pi$. (this region can also be broken down as $\frac16 + \text{blah}$ as described in the earlier post. See the comments there and also the last figure here on the right)

We already see here that the functional form is the same for any radial density $f_r$. Below we will see that

$$T(r) = \cos^{-1}\bigl( \frac{-r}{2R}\bigr) \qquad \text{so that} ~~ \pi - T(r) = \cos^{-1}\bigl( \frac{r}{2R}\bigr) $$

Note that the $\frac1{2\pi}$ either will be absorbed or will be cancelled (when doing conditional probability, there's a denominator and the numerator).

[image]

### The angle $\theta$ as a function of $r$ for curve of the left circle arc

A general point on the plane in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ is illustrated in the left figure above.

Consider point $A$ being on the left-circle-arc with a radial distance of $\overline{DA} = r$,  the angle is a function of the radial distance $\theta = T(r)$. This is illustrated as the figure on the right above.

Let's focus on the triangle $\triangle DAQ$, as shown in the left diagram below. We will obtain the auxiliary angle $\alpha$ (color in red) first, which has a fixed relation with $\theta$.

By the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), we have

$$\cos \alpha = \frac{|QD|^2 + |QA|^2  - |DA|^2}{ 2 \cdot |QD| \cdot |QA|} = \frac{ 2R^2 - r^2}{ 2R^2} = 1 - \frac{ r^2 }{ 2 R^2 }$$

[image]

At the same time, $\triangle DAQ$ is isosceles so the base angle $\angle ADQ = \dfrac{\pi - \alpha}2$. Hence, we have
$$\theta = \pi - \angle ADQ = \dfrac{\pi + \alpha}2 \quad \implies \cos\theta = \cos\bigl( \frac{\pi + \alpha}2 \bigr) = -\sin \frac{\alpha}2 $$
With basic trigonometry, note that $\alpha$ is always acute (its sine is always positive), we have

$$ \cos\alpha = 1 - 2 \sin^2\frac{\alpha}2 \quad \implies \sin\frac{\alpha}2 = \sqrt{ \frac{1 - \cos\alpha}2 } = \sqrt{ \frac{r^2}{ 4R^2} } = \frac{r}{ 2R } \\
\cos\theta = -\frac{r}{ 2R } \qquad \implies \theta = \cos^{-1} \bigl(  \frac{-r}{ 2R } \bigr)$$
as promised.

The last figure on the right is showing the convenient breakdown of the desired $\Omega = UQWD$ region (half of it). It consists of a circular sector (subtending an angle of $\pi/3$), which always contain $\frac16$ of the total mass for rotationally symmetric distribution, and the purple region that requires an integration which has no closed form.

Comment: This is impressively nice! Thank you very much for this explanation